# Help with tree recursion

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I have a Person class, and I want to create a tree. Here is the contsructor for the Person class.

```
public Person(String name, int age, char gender, Person c1, Person c2)
```

c1 is the child on the left, and c2 is the child on the right. And so say I create three Persons like so:

```
Person c = new Person("Carl", 50, 'M', null, f);

Person b = new Person("Barbara", 52, 'F', d, e);

Person a = new Person("Adam", 75, 'M', b, c);
```

So here you say Adam is the root node, and Adam's left child is b, which is Barbara and his right c which is Carl, and so on.

So what I want to do is write a count method, that counts the number of children including `this`. So a.count() would return 6 (if Person f doesnt have any children).

And so here's the code I have:

```
public int count() // total person count including this object
{
    if(child1==null)
        return 0; //I tried return 1 for this too didnt work
    if (child2==null)
        return 0; //also tried 1 for this
    return 1+this.child1.count() +1+this.child2.count();
}
```

I ran this on paper several times, and it should come up with the correct result, but it's off by a few for some reason when I actually run it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code returns `0` if one of the children are `null`. This is incorrect because you don't account for the other child, or `this`.  The count should always be `>= 1` because you always have at least one node in the tree.

Also, you can't return right away if you see that one child is `null`.  You need to count the other child too (if it exists).

Here is how I would implement it:

```
public int count() // total person count including this object
{
    int count = 1; // we count this node as 1 
    if (child1 != null) // if we have a left child, count its size
        count += child1.count();
    if (child2 != null) // if we have a right child, count its size
        count += child2.count()
    return count;
}
```

You need to account for both children, even if one of them is `null`.

Comment: @fprime, your code returns 0 if one of the children are `null`.  This is incorrect because you don't account for the other child, or `this`.

Comment: Originally I had if null return 1 for both, and that didnt work either, even though it should have as well. Why wouldnt that work

Comment: @fprime, because you can't just return if one child is null.  You also have to count the other children.  (see my update)

Comment: @fprime: if child1 is null you return 0 straight away.  You don't count the number of children of child2, nor the node itself.

Comment: Oh ok I see..so my code 'logic' was correct but the fact that I wasnt checking both children was the problem? And so if I change the line `count+=child1.count()` to `count=1+child1.count()`, would that be the same?

Comment: @fprime, no. `count+=child1.count()` is equivalent to `count = count + child1.count()`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @fprime, your recursive logic was basically correct.  You had the general idea right.

Answer (score 4):

The result is wrong because you return 0 when a child is null forgetting to count the node itself or the other child.. if it's a leaf node (`child1 == null && child2 == null`) you should anyway return 1.

Something like:

```
return 1 + (child1 == null ? 0 : child1.count()) + (child2 == null ? 0 : child2.count())
```

following your original code it would be something like:

```
if (child1 == null && child2 == null)
  return 1;
else if (child1 == null)
  return 1 + child2.count();
else if (child2 == null)
  return 1 + child1.count();
else
  return 1 + child1.count() + child2.count();
```

but in that case I would say to stick with jjnguy answer which calculates the result partially..

Comment: Impressive code but complicated lol can you make this into if else statement/

Answer (score 0):

```
private int count() {
    return 1 + ((this.child1 != null) ? (this.child1.count()) : (0)) + ((this.child2 != null) ? (this.child2.count()) : (0));
}
```