# Stop recursion after a certain amount of steps

Tags: java, recursion, tree

This problem is confusing me. I have a tree, and I want to write a method that counts the number of grandchildren of a certain node (but not great granchildren). I cant use loops, only recursion. So the question is how would I implement my base case? How do I make it stop? I can't think of a way that this would be implemented...

Comment: Fun fact: some languages only have recursion; no loops.

Comment: @fprime: regarding your update, I can't see how this could work at all.  You're not passing anything to the recursive calls of `countGrandChildren()`.

Comment: Why would I pass anything? I'm not supposed to..

Comment: @fprime: Please re-read my answer and example code below.

Comment: I cant choose what parameter to take. I have to make a method that does not take a parameter and returns an int.

Comment: @fprime: The only way to avoid passing the `depth` parameter is to maintain the count somewhere else (e.g. a `static` member variable).  This would be a very bad design, though.

Comment: @fprime, can your method call another new method that has the hop-count parameter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help with Java Tree Recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114961/help-with-java-tree-recursion)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a `depth` argument to your recursive method, and have it add 1 before it self-calls, i.e.:

```
void myMethod(int depth) {
    /* ... Do something ... */
    if (depth < maxDepth) {
        child.myMethod(depth + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does maxDepth come from?  Wouldn't it be better to have a depthRemaining which decremented with each call, when the depth reaches 0, stop.

Answer (score 2):

Pass in a "recursion depth" parameter to your recursive function, incrementing it for every call to the function.

When you hit your limit, you stop recursing.