# Counting number of grandchildren in a tree

Tags: java, recursion, tree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop recursion after a certain amount of steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115096/stop-recursion-after-a-certain-amount-of-steps)

What would be wrong with this method here for counting the number of grandchildren in a tree, but not great grandchildren?

(child1 is left child and child2 is right child) Also, this method should not take any parameters. If you offer an alternative solution, please also tell me whats wrong with my current solution..

```
  public int countGrandChildren() // but not greatGrandChildren
    {
        int count=0;
        int depth=1;
        if (depth<4){
            if (child1!=null){
                count+=child1.countGrandChildren();
                depth++;
                if (depth==3)
                    count++;
            }
            if (child2!=null){
                count+=child2.countGrandChildren();
                depth++;
                if (depth==3)
                    count++;    
            }   
        }
        return count;

    }
```

Comment: Please don't create a new question that's essentially the same as your old question...

Comment: Well no one was helping me with the other question

Comment: All possible (reasonable) answers were given in the previous question.  Asking the question again won't change that fact!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115096

Answer (score 0):

How would this work if you don't pass depth to each recursion call? Depth is always 1 at start and then you may increment it. but it will never be == 3.

Comment: Why is there a requirement to not have a parameter for the function? Did the assignment say that?

Comment: But depth is being incremented..

Comment: I don't think you understand scope of variable really well. When you declare an "int depth" its only valid for that function, the next time you call countGrandChildren, depth will be 0 again.

Answer (score 0):

As already discussed at [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115096/stop-recursion-after-a-certain-amount-of-steps), you're not passing any parameters between successive recursive calls, so how could they possibly terminate?

`int depth = 1; if (depth < 4) ...` will *always* be the case!

The solutions are variations on one of the following possibilities:

- pass a `depth` (or equivalent) parameter recursively
- maintain the count elsewhere (bad)
- assign each instance of the class a `myDepth` member variable at construction based on its position in the tree (this will be a pain if you ever need to rearrange items in the tree)

Comment: but I'm incrementing depth everytime I go in a deeper level

Comment: @prime: `depth` is local to each call to `countGreatGrandchildren()`, and you set it to 1 at the beginning of the function. It's a different `depth` variable in each call (and it's always initialized to 1).

Comment: @fprime: No, you're not.  You have `depth` as a local variable, so it's reinitialised to 1 every time you call the method.

Comment: Then the only choice I have is to maintain count elsewhere. How would I do that?

Comment: @fprime: As I suggested in a comment to your previous question, you could use, for instance, a `static` member variable of the class.  (But as I also said, this is not a good solution.)

Comment: My code works fine though, except for the fact that the parent node has 3 grandchildren and 1 null grandchild, which shouldnt count. But my code counts it. So the test expects 3 but it gives it 4..how can this be if you say my code doesnt work?

Comment: @fprime: Your code cannot possibly work.  It may appear to "almost work" for your particular test case, but try altering your test case (e.g. try a case where there are great-grandchildren, or great-great-grandchildren).

Comment: Ok I decleared a static depth integer in the class and set it equal to 1. Now its passing most test cases but not where the tree is unbalanced (where the left child has no children and the right one does)

Comment: @fprime: I have no idea, unless you post the code into your question.

Comment: It's just `private static int depth=1;`

Comment: @fprime: Ok.  Well if you're still using the code in your question, then the local definition `int depth = 1;` will hide the static member variable.  Also, you will need to decrement `depth` every time you come back out of the recursion.  Also, you will need to reset `depth` to 0 before you call `countGrandChildren()` at the top-level.

Comment: I'm confused:( Decrement and reset depth?? I have no idea what youre talking about. How would you merge this with my code?

Comment: Keeping track of search depth using a static int won't work. The left branch of the tree will get traversed to the desired depth before it even starts on the right side of the head node.

Comment: @fprime: If you don't understand what I mean, then may I suggest adding `System.out.println("depth = " + depth);` somewhere in your `countGrandChildren()` method; it should become obvious...

Comment: @fbcocq: It will work, just not with the OP's current code...

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to pass the depth variable as a parameter of the function here is a simpler example that calculates the factorial of a number by calling the function recursively but subtracting 1 from the argument passed each time.

```
public int calcFactorial(int facnum){
    int res;
    if (facnum==1){
        res=1;
        }
     else {
        res=facnum*calcFactorial(facnum-1);
        }        

}
```