# Counting genders through tree recursion

Tags: java, tree

I have a Person class with the following constructor:

```
public Person(String name, int age, char gender, Person c1, Person c2)
```

where c1 is the left child and c2 is the right child. I want to write a method that counts the number of Persons that match the given gender, either M or F:

```
public int countGender(char gen)
{
    int count=0;
    if (this.gender==gen){
        count++;
    }
    if (child1!=null){
        if (child1.gender==gen){
            count+=1+child1.countGender(gen);
        }
        else count+=child1.countGender(gen);
    }
    if (child2!=null){
        if (child2.gender==gen){
            count+=1+child2.countGender(gen);
        }
        else count+=child2.countGender(gen);
    }
    return count;
}
```

I've tried just about everything. I'm having a hard time imagining what happens to count every time the function calls itself. Does it reset? Or since I'm using +=, does it save itself kind of before it resets? What else is wrong with my method? Please help me understand.

Comment: Again, please post input, expected output and actual output with these types of questions. Also, tell us how you're testing this, what are you observing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help with Java Tree Recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114961/help-with-java-tree-recursion)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each invocation of `countGender` has its own `count` variable, initialised to zero.

You need don't need to examine the gender of a `Person`'s two children, as the recursive calls for each of those children can do that. For example:

```
public int countGender(char gen) {

    int count = 0;

    if (this.gender == gen) {
        count++;
    }

    if (child1 != null) {
        count += child1.countGender(gen);
    }

    if (child2 != null) {
        count += child2.countGender(gen);
    }

    return count;
}
```

You can think of `p.countGender(...)` as giving you the number of people, with the specified gender, in the tree that has `p` at its root.

This is the sum of:

- 1, if `p` has the correct gender
- the number of people with the correct gender in the **left** subtree of `p` (if there is one)
- the number of people with the correct gender in the **right** subtree of `p` (if there is one).

The code given above performs a [depth-first traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_Traversal) of the tree of people. It's actually a **preorder** traversal (deal with the root node, followed by its left and right subtrees). It's also possible to do an **inorder** traversal (left subtree, then the node itself, then the right subtree), or a **postorder** traversal (left subtree, then right subtree, then the node itself).

For counting nodes, as you do here, the order doesn't actually matter: the result will be the same. For certain operations, though, such as displaying all the people in the tree, it does matter.

Comment: Wow it was this simple huh..I should have thought about this. I'm new to recursion still trying to learn the tricks...thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're adding 1 too many times.  Every time an child runs `countGender`, it adds 1 to the count if it is the correct gender (line 5).  But, you're checking the child's gender again at lines 9 and 15, even though each child checks its own gender.  Thus, you're double-counting everything.

As for recursion, every call of `countGender` is distinct and separate from any other calls.  Each instance's `count` is a separate variable in memory, and it's initialized to 0 every time.